# Is $[0,\infty)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove whether or not there exists a homeomorphism between $[0,\infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I started by saying that $[0,\infty$) is closed in the Euclidean topology because its complement $(-\infty,0)$ is open. But then I got stuck! I know $(0,\infty)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with $\log(x)$.

Any hints?

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is also open but not closed in its one-point compactification $[0,\infty]$, for that matter.

Comment: You recieved two answers to your question. Is any of them what you were looking for? If so, consider accepting it, and also upvote any answer that was usefull to you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you remove $0$ from $[0,+\infty)$, what you get is $(0,+\infty)$, which is connected. But if you remove a point from $\mathbb R$, you'll get a disconnected space. Therefore, they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: While true, the OP may not know that *the restriction of a homeomorphism into a smaller domain is also a homeomorphism, from its domain to its range*.

Comment: @Myridium That's an easy exercise!

Comment: @SahibaArora - okay, yes, sure, but will the OP think to do such an exercise unprompted, purely from the text contained in this answer? I think not.

Comment: @Myridium I think that answer is sufficient to push OP in the right direction and fill in any blanks.

Comment: @SahibaArora - this is a Q&A site, right? Seriously though, I hope so.

Comment: @Myridium [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22266/266110) might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a property of a homeomorphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ that the restriction of $f$ into a smaller domain, call it $\chi \subseteq X$, is also a homeomorphism: $f\vert_\chi : \chi \rightarrow f(X)$.

With this out of the way, suppose there was a homeomorphism $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$. It then follows that we can restrict this to the domain $(0,\infty)$, leading to the conclusion that $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R -\{f(0)\}$ is also a homeomorphism. However, as others have said, removing a single point from $\mathbb R$ leaves it disconnected, while the interval $(0,\infty)$ is connected. Since homeomorphisms preserve the number of connected components, we have a contradiction.